# Rails count number of checkboxes in a view before posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have little knowledge of Javascript, but I think it might be the only way to make things work in my problem.
I am using rails 5.
I basically have checkboxes in a view that represent a price, and every time I check or uncheck one, I would like to update the total price for that view (that I then pass in a hidden_field and a post request).
I'm guessing that what I have to do is get an onclick event going everytime I check or uncheck a box, and update a variable that I then show in the view.

I've found something that looks very similar to my case, but unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce it: [Rails Jquery compute total from selected checkboxes in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704155/rails-jquery-compute-total-from-selected-checkboxes-in-a-table)

I have my checkboxes with a class "checkbox-count", and I can send an alert everytime I check them, but that's about all I have so far...

Your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled on the server side by getting an array(checkbox names are all the same array value) of the checked boxes values in a controller action and adding the values together there, maybe you have a reason not to though?

Otherwise this is more of a javascript question, but it could be handled with some vanilla javascript like this maybe:

```js
// a quick custom function for calculating total values of all checked checkboxes in a given form
function calcFormCheckedBoxesTotal(form) {
  total = 0;
  form.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").forEach(checked_box => {
    total += parseInt(checked_box.getAttribute("value"));
  });
  return total;
}

// get all form checkbox inputs to be used 
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("form input.checkbox-count"); 

// loop through all given form checkbox inputs so we can...
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => { 
  // ... add click event listener to each checkbox
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', event => {
  
    // ... use my custom function to calculate totals of all checked boxes in the parent form of currently clicked on checkbox and store in "total" variable
    total = calcFormCheckedBoxesTotal(event.target.parentElement);
  
    // ... change value of my text input with id="total_price" to show total of checked boxes. Change the target of the querySelector to whatever you want to update(your hidden field) with the total.
    document.querySelector("#total_price").value = total; 
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-count" name="price[]" value="25"><label>$25</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-count" name="price[]" value="50"><label>$50</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-count" name="price[]" value="100"><label>$100</label><br>
  
  <input type="text" id="total_price" name="total_price" value="0">
</form>
```